# Conditionally Change a Gradle Property Based on a Provider Value

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm writing a Gradle convention plugin that uses Gradle's [Lazy Configuration APIs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) to configure tasks. In one case, the plugin needs to conditionally change the value of a `Property`, and that condition is based on the effective value of a `Provider`. That is, if the `Provider` has a certain value, update the value of the `Property`; else, leave the `Property` as-is.

If not for the `Provider` semantics, this would be a simple logic statement like:

```kotlin
if (someValue > 10) {
  property.set(someValue)
}
```

but, because the `Provider`'s value is not-yet-known, this is more complicated.

I naively tried the following, but it results in a stack overflow error, because the transformer for the property includes a retrieval of that same property.

```kotlin
// stack overflow error
property.set(provider.map { if (it > 10) it else property.get() })
```

A more complete example:

```kotlin
val foo = objects.property(String::class).convention("foo")
val bar = objects.property(String::class).convention("bar")

bar.set(foo.map { if (it != "foo") "baz" else bar.get()})


tasks.register("print") {
    // goal is to print "baz", but it is a StackOverflowError
    logger.log(LogLevel.LIFECYCLE, bar.get())
}
```

Is there an API I'm missing that would allow me to conditionally update the value of a `Property` based on the value of a `Provider`?

Comment: I think you want to use `zip` to combine two providers. https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Provider.html#zip-org.gradle.api.provider.Provider-java.util.function.BiFunction-

Comment: I did try `zip`, but I still got stack overflow errors when assigning the result of the `zip` to one of the `Property` instances passed to `zip`.

Comment: Ah okay, I've got a better idea, but I'm not clear on when exactly you want to perform your conditional check. Do you want to do it in the task action? Or can you do it in a `doFirst { }` block? Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: Updated with a more complete example :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your simplified example, you don't actually need providers.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
val foo = objects.property(String::class).convention("foo")
val bar = objects.property(String::class).convention("bar")

tasks.register("print") {
    val evaluatedFoo = if (foo.get() != "foo") "baz" else bar.get()
    logger.lifecycle("evaluatedFoo $evaluatedFoo")
}
// output:
// evaluatedFoo bar
```

That's because the logger is working in the configuration phase (see 'Gradle Phases Recap' below). Usually (but not always) properties and providers are to avoid computation during the configuration phase.

> sidenote: `property` vs `provider`
>
> The difference is akin to Kotlin's `var` and `val`. `property` should be used for letting a user set a custom value, `provider` is for read-only values, like environment variables `providers.environmentVariable("HOME")`.

#### Why use providers?

Because you're using 'register', [the task isn't configured until it's required](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:how_do_i_defer_creation). So I'll tweak your example to make things a bit worse, to see how ugly it gets.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
val foo: Provider<String> = providers.provider {
    // pretend we're doing some heavy work, like an API call
    Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10))
    "foo"
}
val bar = objects.property(String::class).convention("bar")

// change from 'register' to 'create'
tasks.create("print") {
    val evaluatedFoo = if (foo.get() != "foo") "baz" else bar.get()
    logger.lifecycle("evaluatedFoo: $evaluatedFoo")
}
```

Now **every time** Gradle loads `build.gradle.kts`, it takes 10 seconds! Even if we don't run a task! Or an unrelated task! That won't do. This is one good justification for using providers.

### Solutions

There are a few different paths here, depending on what you actually want to achieve.

#### Only log in the execution phase

We can move the log statement to a `doFirst {}` or `doLast {}` block. The contents of these blocks run in the execution phase. That's the point of the providers, to delay work until this phase. So we can call `.get()` to evaluate them.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
tasks.create("print") {
    doFirst {
        // now we're in the execution phase, it's okay to crack open the providers
        val evaluatedFoo = if (foo.get() != "foo") "baz" else bar.get()
        logger.lifecycle("evaluatedFoo: $evaluatedFoo")
    }
}
```

Now even though the task is eagerly created, `foo` and `bar` won't be evaluated until execution time - when it's okay to do work.

#### Combine two providers

I think this option is closer to what you were originally asking. Instead of recursively setting `baz` back into itself, create a new provider.

Gradle will only evaluate `foo` and `bar` when `fooBarZipped.get()` is called.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
val foo = objects.property(String::class).convention("foo")
val bar = objects.property(String::class).convention("bar")

val fooBarZipped: Provider<String> = foo.zip(bar) { fooActual, barActual ->
    if (fooActual != "foo") {
        "baz"
    } else {
        barActual
    }
}

tasks.register("print") {
    logger.lifecycle("fooBarZipped: ${fooBarZipped.get()}")
}
```

Note that this `fooBarZipped.get()` will also cause `bar` to be evaluated, even though it might not be used! In this case we can just use `map()` (which is different to Kotlin's `Collection<T>.map()` extension function!)

#### Mapping providers

This one is a little more lazy.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
val foo = objects.property(String::class).convention("foo")
val bar = objects.property(String::class).convention("bar")

val fooBarMapped: Provider<String> = foo.map { fooActual ->
    if (fooActual != "foo") {
        "baz"
    } else {
        bar.get() // bar will only be evaluated if required
    }
}

tasks.register("print") {
    logger.lifecycle("evaluatedFoo: ${fooBarMapped.get()}")
}
```

### Custom task

Sometimes it's easier to define tasks in a `build.gradle.kts`, but often it's more clear to specifically make a `MyPrintTask` class. This part is optional - do whatever is best for your situation.

It's a lot to learn the strange Gradle style of creating tasks, so I won't dive into it all. But the point I want to make is that `@get:Input` is really important.

```kotlin
// buildSrc/main/kotlin/MyPrintTask.kt
package my.project

abstract class MyPrintTask : DefaultTask() {
    @get:Input
    abstract val taskFoo: Property<String>
    @get:Input
    abstract val taskBar: Property<String>

    @get:Internal
    val toBePrinted: Provider<String> = project.provider {
        if (taskFoo.get() != "foo") {
            "baz"
        } else {
            taskBar.get()
        }
    }

    @TaskAction
    fun print() {
        logger.quiet("[PrintTask] ${toBePrinted.get()}")
    }
}
```

> Aside: you can also define inputs with the Kotlin DSL, but it's not quite as fluid
>
> ```kotlin
> //build.gradle.kts
> tasks.register("print") {
>     val taskFoo = foo // setting the property here helps Gradle configuration cache
>     inputs.property("taskFoo", foo)
>     val taskBar = foo
>     inputs.property("taskBar", bar)
>     
>     doFirst {
>         val evaluated = if (taskFoo.get() != "foo") {
>             "baz"
>         } else {
>             taskBar.get()
>         }
>         logger.lifecycle(evaluated)
>     }
> }
> ```

Now you can define the task in the build script.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
val foo = objects.property(String::class).convention("foo")
val bar = objects.property(String::class).convention("bar")

tasks.register<MyPrintTask>("print") {
    taskFoo.set(foo)
    taskBar.set(bar)
}
```

It doesn't seem like there's much benefit here, but `@get:Input` can be really important if `foo` or `bar` are themselves mapped or zipped, or depend on the output of a task. Now Gradle will chain tasks together, so even if you just run `gradle :print`, it knows how to trigger a whole cascade of necessary precursor tasks!

---

#### Gradle phases recap

[Gradle has 3 phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)

1. Initialization - projects are loaded, inside `settings.gradle.kts`. That's not interesting for us right now.
2. Configuration - this is what happens when loading `build.gradle.kts`, or defining a task
3. Execution - a task is triggered! Tasks run, providers and properties are computed.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
println("This is executed during the configuration phase.")

tasks.register("configured") {
    println("This is also executed during the configuration phase, because :configured is used in the build.")
}

tasks.register("test") {
    doLast {
        println("This is executed during the execution phase.")
    }
}

tasks.register("testBoth") {
    doFirst {
        println("This is executed first during the execution phase.")
    }
    doLast {
        println("This is executed last during the execution phase.")
    }
    println("This is executed during the configuration phase as well, because :testBoth is used in the build.")
}
```

#### Task Configuration Avoidance

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html

Why is this relevant to providers and properties? Because they ensure 2 things

1. **work is not done during the configuration phase**

   When Gradle registers a task, we don't want it to actually run the task! we want to delay that until it's needed.
2. **Gradle can create a 'directed acyclic graph'**

   Basically, Gradle isn't a single-track production line, with a single starting point. It's a hive-mind of little workers that have input and output, and Gradle chains the workers together based on where they get the input from.

Comment: I've caused more confusion by trying to simplify my example. What I'm actually trying to do is configure the compile task, and change one of the `Property` objects belonging to the compile task based on another `Provider` belonging to the compile task.

I think this answers the question:

> properties and providers are to avoid computation during the configuration phase

Can freely call `get()` on a provider belonging to the task in the task's configuration block, because that block runs in the configuration phase, and the point of the provider is to defer computation until that phase.

Comment: Understood! If anything is unclear or you'd like to use a different example, please ask a new question and link it here!